# Delete GET params from current URL

Tags: javascript, php, url

Currently i'm using a javascript to confirm a form.

```
echo "<script>
var x = document.URL;
var r = confirm('Are you sure?');
if (r == true) {
window.location.search += '&answer=1'; 
 </script>";
```

so it add the get param "answer", and in my php file i check the number (if answered "Cancel it returns 0), but i need to delete this param from my url after checking it, but I didn't find anything to do it.

my URL should be like this in the process.

```
starting url = www.myurl.com
```

**user send the form, and answers "yes" to the question**

```
current url = www.myurl.com?answer=1;
```

**php check the get variable and to things if answered "yes", after finish the function it modified the url**

```
url after php function = www.myurl.com
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Request string without GET arguments in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504608/request-string-without-get-arguments-in-php)

Comment: Why not just `redirect` using [PHP header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), i.e. `header('Location: http://www.myurl.com')` to the `www.myurl.com` after you've done checking in your `PHP` script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to remove the parameters:

```
window.location.search = '';
```

Comment: but this doesn't modify my current URL.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current page URL **without** GET parameters:

```
console.log(window.location.origin + window.location.pathname);
```