# Echoing Only The Page Name (No Query)

Tags: php

I'm trying to check my php url up to the point before the query string begins.

Currently I have this: `http://example.com/my-post-here.php?utm_source=webclick&utm_ad_id=123` so im only trying to check for `my-post-here.php`

The code I'm working with so far is:

```
$url = trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/');
echo $url;
```

This has worked fine up until i added the code after `my-post-here.php` so how do I still continue to check for only `my-post-here.php` and disregard everything else?

Comment: Try `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` maybe ? http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php. Additionally, you can always try `var_dump($_SERVER)`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request string without GET arguments in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504608/request-string-without-get-arguments-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the php explode function to separate the string at the question mark:

```
$array = explode('?', $url);
$newUrl = $array[0];
echo $newUrl; //this will have your url before the question mark
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for the `basename` of the url without it's query parameters.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

```
// your original url
$url = 'http://example.com/my-post-here.php?utm_source=webclick&utm_ad_id=123';

// we don't need the query params
list($url, $queryParams) = explode("?", $url);

// echo the basename
echo basename($url);
```

result:

```
my-post-here.php
```

You can also use `parse_url` as others have noted, but you'll need to strip the `/` character from what it returns.

Comment: First time seeing the function ''list()'' in php ! :o

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it :

```
$url = 'http://example.com/my-post-here.php?utm_source=webclick&utm_ad_id=123';
$parsed = parse_url($url); // parse the url
echo $parsed['path'];  // return /my-post-here.php
```

You should read about the parse_url function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) :