# $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] replace string or charecter

Tags: php, .htaccess

in my online project now i change my content and so, i have to change link too. but,for links that google already registered i have to do this. if server get request like this.

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]="http://example.com/category/?company=listof_ele_top_manufacturers";
```

i want to redirect it to.

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]="http://example.com/category/?company=listof.ele.top.manufacturers";
```

and company= many deffrent values. so,i want to change my url with _(underscore)
to .(dot) so url should change with dot where it's have underscore. if solution come with .htaccess file change will be nice one. i already change my .htaccess file with this.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/com/ http://www.example.com/category/
```

it's redirect my directory name but not charecter i mention above.

Comment: Did you even try to google "php replace char in string"? (The comment bellow shows the first search result, in case you couldn't see it)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: yes. it show for redirect page,directory and domain. not for charecter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^company=([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /category/?company=%1.%2.%3.%4 [QSA,NC,L,R]
```

Or try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /category/\?company=([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /category/?company=%1.%2.%3.%4 [QSA,NC,L,R]
```

This will redirect

```
/?company=foo_bar_foobar
```

to

```
/?company=foo.bar.foobar
```

Comment: it's display in url bar continues like. ?company=listof.ele.top.manufacturers&company=listof.ele.top.manufacturers&company=listof.ele.top.manufacturers&company=listof.ele.top.manufacturers&company=listof.ele.top.manufacturers....

Comment: first with same problem where second one redirect me to home page www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

> mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )

So it would be like this:

```
$new_uri = str_replace("_",".",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
header('Location: '.$new_uri);
```

Ref: [PHP:str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: This won't work on `example.com/file.html?parameters`

Comment: Why?, he just want's to replace all underscores with dots, the link you suggested doesn't need any modification

Comment: Yes, my example was wrong. Consider this: `/some_directory/?parameters`. If he decides to change some part of the url, it will not behave correctly.

Comment: how can i do this in .htaccess file?

Comment: He was asking to replace all underscores to dots not only the query variables, anyway he is looking for .htaccess redirecting now so feel free to tell him bro ;)

Answer (score 0):

before any redirect you just need to check if the "company" param has underscore in it, if yes the url is redirected

```
<?php
$company = $_GET['company'];
if (preg_match('/_/', $company)) {
    // contains an underscore, redirect to new url here, using str_replace function
} else {
    // does not contain any underscore
}
?>
```

Comment: Would be nice to check if `$_GET['company']` isset()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you have missed was the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] variable.

```
/* see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6975045/3132718 */
$url = strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?');

/* add the parameter part */
$url .= str_replace("_", ".", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
header("Location: $url");
```