# How to get file name from url without $_GET variable?

Tags: php, url

```
http://localhost/mc/site-01-up/index.php?c=lorem-ipsum

$address = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$stack = explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$file = array_pop($stack);
echo $file;
```

result - `index.php?c=lorem-ipsum`

How to get just file name (`index.php`) without `$_GET` variable, using `array_pop` if possible?

Comment: you can use this `__FILE__`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the querystring and get only the url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969645/how-to-remove-the-querystring-and-get-only-the-url)

Comment: https://eval.in/606839 . easy to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will follow `parse_url()` like below (easy to understand):-

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/mc/site-01-up/index.php?c=lorem-ipsum';

$url=   parse_url($url);
print_r($url); // to check what parse_url() will outputs
$url_path = explode('/',$url['path']); // explode the path part
$file_name =  $url_path[count($url_path)-1]; // get last index value which is your desired result

echo $file_name;
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/606839

Note:- tested with your given URL. Check for other type of URL's at your end. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Another method that can get the filename is by using parse_url — Parses a URL and return its components

```
<?php
$url = "http://localhost/mc/site-01-up/index.php?c=lorem-ipsum";
$data = parse_url($url);
$array = explode("/",$data['path']);
$filename = $array[count($array)-1];
var_dump($filename);
```

Result

```
index.php
```

**EDIT:** 
Sorry for posting this answer as it is almost identical to the selected one. I didnt see the answer so posted. But I cannot delete this as it is seen as a bad practice by moderators.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it would be to simply get the `basename()` of the file and then strip-out all the Query Part using regex or better still simply do pass the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` result to the `basename()` Function. Both will yield the same result though the 2nd approach seems a little more intuitive.

```
<?php

    $fileName  = preg_replace("#\?.*$#", "", basename("http://localhost/mc/site-01-up/index.php?c=lorem-ipsum"));
    echo $fileName;  // DISPLAYS: index.php

    // OR SHORTER AND SIMPLER:
    $fileName   = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    echo $fileName;  // DISPLAYS: index.php
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, not tested:

```
    $file = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
    $parts = Explode('/', $file);
    $file = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
    echo $file;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the GET method without variable name, another option would be using the $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]

http://something.com/index.php?=somestring

$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] would return "somestring"