# htaccess mod rewriting | remove variable sign and all unnecessary text

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a dayanmic website built in core PHP/MySql and hosted on one.com, I'm trying to make my URLs SEO Friendly by removing all Unnecessary signs from the URL, especially the variable `?someid=`

I tried a lot of scripts using htaccess but nothing worked.

currently my url look like this: `example.com/category.php?post-title=بعض-النص-يذهب-هنا`

I want it to look like this: `example.com/بعض-النص-يذهب-هنا`

The title is stored in a MySql database.

as I mentioned I tried a lot of mod rewriting but nothing worked, here is one of the scripts I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ([^/]*)\.html category.php?post-title=$1
```

There is more scripts I tried, I can post them too if it's important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to use is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /category.php?post-title=$1 [L]
```

It will leave you with your desired URL of: `example.com/بعض-النص-يذهب-هنا`. Just make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: What if I have more than one Category that I want to rewrite, I mean I have `category.php?post-title=$1` and I have `category2.php?post-title=$1` , I tried to do the same method but all is been redirected to one cateogry.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this in root directory and mod-rewrite must be enabled for rewriting,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ category.php?post-title=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I assume you are trying this url in your browser example.com/بعض-النص-يذهب-هنا and you have category.php file stored in directory where you have your .htaccess file?

Comment: Do you mean cached files, if so, I have cleared all the history and cached files and still getting the same result, I have contacted my host also and they said mod rewriting is enabled on Apache Server

Comment: The htaccess file is in the root directory 
@Abhishek gurjar

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
$pageURL = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {
    $pageURL .= "s";
}
$pageURL .= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ":" .
        $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
} else {
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

If any query follow below links

[How to remove the querystring and get only the url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969645/how-to-remove-the-querystring-and-get-only-the-url)

[Removing query string in PHP (sometimes based on referrer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270677/removing-query-string-in-php-sometimes-based-on-referrer)

Answer (score 0):

If i just follow your example you just need this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) /category.php?post-title=$1
```

But this will match every time the hole path.

Maybe you should prefix your category paths like

```
RewriteRule category/(.*)\.html /category.php?post-title=$1
```

So every category has path like /category/بعض-النص-يذهب-هنا.html