# PHP Remove anything after specific characters (file extensions)

Tags: php, regex, explode, substr, file-extension

I would like to remove anything that follows after a specific set of characters (i.e. filetypes / extensions). I have tried numerous scripts I found online, but none really manage to do what I need, they either remove the file extension as well, or keep parts of the arguments that follow.

```
$urls = array(
'http://www.example.com/images/image1.jpg',
'http://www.example.com/images/image2.png?arg=value',
'http://www.example.com/images/image3.jpg?foo=bar',
'http://www.example.com/images/image4.gif?v=1',
'http://www.example.com/images/image5.bmp?x=y',
'http://www.example.com/images/image6.tiff?werdfs=234234'
);
```

Desired outcome:

```
http://www.example.com/images/image1.jpg
http://www.example.com/images/image2.png
http://www.example.com/images/image3.jpg
http://www.example.com/images/image4.gif
http://www.example.com/images/image5.bmp
http://www.example.com/images/image6.tiff
```

Comment: https://3v4l.org/uKvjq

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969645/how-to-remove-the-querystring-and-get-only-the-url

Comment: why doesn't `$urls = array_map(function($item){ return explode("?", $item)[0]; }, $urls);` work for you? Is there an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this one help you.

```php
$re = '/^.*(?:\.)[a-zA-Z]+/m';
$urls = array(
'http://www.example.com/images/image1.jpg',
'http://www.example.com/images/image2.png?arg=value',
'http://www.example.com/images/image3.jpg?foo=bar',
'http://www.example.com/images/image4.gif?v=1',
'http://www.example.com/images/image5.bmp?x=y',
'http://www.example.com/images/image6.tiff?werdfs=234234',
'asdasd'
);

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    preg_match($re, $url, $matches);
    if ($matches) {
        echo $matches[0];
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

### Output

```
http://www.example.com/images/image1.jpg
http://www.example.com/images/image2.png
http://www.example.com/images/image3.jpg
http://www.example.com/images/image4.gif
http://www.example.com/images/image5.bmp
http://www.example.com/images/image6.tiff
```

Answer (score 0):

How about PHP's parse_url() and basename?

```php
$inName = $urls[0]; // for example
$newName = parse_url($inName,PHP_URL_SCHEME)
         . parse_url($inName,PHP_URL_HOST)
         . parse_url($inName,PHP_URL_PATH)
         . basename($inName);
```